# Unable to find element in iframes using Selenium WebDriver Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver

I am trying to automatically load charts on www.investing.com. My main aim is to click the "load chart layout" button which can be found at https://www.investing.com/charts/live-charts (third button from the top right in the chart iframe, looks like a cloud). Being new to selenium, I learned about iframes and after some inspection I found that the button is located in an iframe which in in an iframe which is in an iframe. I am finally correctly switching to the iframe that contains the button but for some reason the find_element_by_xxx function always says not found whether I use class, id, xpath or whatever. My code is as follows

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def findFrames(driver):
    iframes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//iframe')
    i = 0
    index = 0
    for iframe in iframes:
        print(iframe.get_attribute('src'))

        string = iframe.get_attribute('src')
        if "tv" in string:
            index = i
            break
        i+=1
    print(index)
    return iframes, index

def main():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    #chrome_options.add_argument("/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.sBnz8G/Profile 1")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("http://www.investing.com")

    try:
        #time.sleep(10)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/header/div[1]/div/div[4]/span[1]/div/a[1]").click()
        time.sleep(3)
    except:
        print("first block")

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'loginPopup')))
        print("found")
    except:
        print("not found")

    try:
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id("loginFormUser_email")
        elem.click()
        elem.send_keys("my-email")
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id("loginForm_password")
        elem.click()
        elem.send_keys("my-password")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(3)
    except: 
        print("second block")


    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="navMenu"]/ul/li[5]/a').click()
    print("charts clicked")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/section/div[4]/div[1]/a").click()
    print("live charts clicked")
    time.sleep(20)
    iframes, index = findFrames(driver)
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[index])
    print("switch 1")
    iframes, index = findFrames(driver)
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[index])
    print("switch 2")
    iframes, index = findFrames(driver)
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[index])
    print("switch 3")

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/span[1]/svg').click() #THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
    print("successfully clicked load")
    time.sleep(1.5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Can someone find out why it says not found even though I switch to the correct frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load chart layout` is present inside nested `iframes`.

To handle dynamic element
Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() following `css`selector

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `css`selector

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/section/div[4]/div[1]/a").click()
print("live charts clicked")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='tvc_frame']")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src$='GB']")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='tradingview']")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.save-load-buttons>span.load"))).click()
print("successfully clicked load")
```

You need to import following libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Hey I understand that. The iframes and everything load and I successfully switch to them too but still the final element is not found.

Comment: The code executed successfully on my machine.did you copy my entire code and executed.

Comment: I tried it and it's working! Not sure what was wrong with my code but this helped a lot! Thank you!